# I am unable to write data in an array of type reg. It is default writing xxxx into this

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
`include "top.v"
`include "c_top.v"

module fixture;

reg [31:0]F[0:100];
reg [31:0]F2[0:50];
reg [31:0]F3[0:50];
reg [31:0]a,b;
reg clk,reset,s;

wire [31:0]r_expected,r_actual;
wire exception_expected,exception_actual;

integer i;
integer j=32;

integer k;
integer m,u;

topdut t1(a,b,s,clk,reset,r_actual,exception_actual);
c_toptest t2(a,b,s,clk,reset,r_expected,exception_expected);

initial 
begin
clk = 1'b1;
forever #10 clk = ~clk;
end

//initial
 //$monitor($time,"clk=%b  reset =%b a=%h b=%h s=%b exception=%b  r=%h ",clk,reset,a,b,s,exception,r);

integer ab;

initial
begin
        ab=$fopen("input_ab.txt","w");
        for(i=0;i<100;i=i+1)
            begin
                $fdisplay(ab,"%b",$random());
            end
        $fclose(ab);

end

initial
begin
        $readmemb("input_ab.txt",F);
end

always@(posedge clk or negedge reset)
begin
    if(!reset)
    begin
    a <= 32'b0;
    b <= 32'b0;
    k <= 0;
    m <=0;


u <=0;
    end
    else
    begin
    a <= F[k];
    b <= F[k+50];
    k <= k+1;
    $display("r is %b and m is %i",r_expected,m);
    F2[m] <= r_expected;
    m <= m+1;
    if(k>=29)
    begin
    F3[u] <= r_actual;
    u <= u+1;
    end
    end
end 
initial
begin
    for(i=0;i<100;i = i+1)
    begin
        $display("c%b c2%b a%b b%b",F2[i],F3[i],F[i],F[i+50]);
        end

end

initial 
begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        reset = 1'b0;
    #30
    reset = 1'b1;
    s = 1'b0;

   end
    initial 
    begin
            #1500 $finish; 
    end



endmodule
```

When I display F2[] and F3[] it is taking xxxxxxx.
Even though m and r are having valid values.

Please suggest some solution.
I know there is a small glitch here.

I guess all my declarations are correct.

All my modules are giving correct output from DUT.
Only in this testbench something is wrong

Comment: Size of both F2 and F3 is 50. But you a looping in range 0..100, don't you?

Comment: How is r_actual and r_expected assigned in code ? What are top_dut and c_toptest doing ?
On side note, why are using so many `initial` blocks? Try to club it in one for make it more readable and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

The reg declarations are initialized to x.  The display statement executes at time zero before F2 and F3 have been assigned to other values.  The correct initial values of x are displayed.